# how to use switch case statement to filter result set based on condition in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, conditional-statements, switch-statement

i am working on a task where i am sending a status as parameter in request and want to filter based on that status and one other column from database table but that is not passed from request.

so it is like

when status is incomplete and Key value in db is null then fetch records fullfilling this criteria (awaiting)

when status is incomplete and Key value in db is not null then fetch records fullfilling this criteria
(pending review)

when status is suspended then fetch records fullfilling this criteria
(rejected)

when status is Succeeded then fetch records fullfilling this criteria
(approved)

when status is Failed then fetch records fullfilling this criteria
(Failed)

```
public class StatusRequest
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public Task<StatusSearchResponse> Handle(StatusRequest request)
{
var projects = Repository.GetProjects(request.Status);
switch (request.Status)
{
    case Status.Incomplete && projects .Any(x => x.Key == null):
        projects.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Incomplete && x.Key == null);
        break;
    case Status.Suspended:
        break;
    case Status.Succeeded:
        break;
    case Status.Failed:
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}

var response = new StatusSearchResponse();
response.Projects = projects;
return SystemTask.FromResult(response);
}
```

so my code is as follows
Or without switch statement can i use **stored procedure** to do so can anybody suggest please

Comment: I think we need a bit more context here. Like what exactly is it that gives you trouble/you dont know how to achieve? And what does your Projects class look like?

Comment: How about `projects.Where(x => x.Status == request.Status ...` ?

Comment: `Repository.GetProjects` does that get you an `IQueryable<T>` or an `IEnumerable<T>` ? I'd also recommend to materialize if you return the response. so add `async` modifier and `response.Projects = await projects.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);`

Comment: In C#, the switch statement doesn't support conditions like you're trying to use with case Status.Incomplete && projects.Any(x => x.Key == null). switch cases in C# are for simple value matching, not for complex conditions. To achieve what you want, you could use a series of if statements instead or you can try storeprocedure.

Answer (score 1):

`projects.Where(...)` doesn't "do" anything to 'projects' but it returns a new list (enumerable).

So change that line to

```
projects = projects.Where(x => x.Status == Status.Incomplete && x.Key == null).ToList();
```

- You probably need a .ToList() to convert from the IEnumerable that `.Where()` returns to a list (that I assume 'projects' is)
- And (important!) assign that list back to 'projects'

Comment: Since the method is returning `Task<T>` already, it's probably also a good idea to go async ...